# Adding custom CSS styling on some of my pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, templates, css

I would like to add custom CSS styling to some of my pages to give them a unique style, and override the default template styling.

How can I achieve this in Joomla?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several ways to add custom CSS code to a specific page. Here's a couple of alternatives:

**Alt. 1 - Page class**
Use page classes. In the menu item editor, under the "Page display" tab, there's a field called "Page class". This will add a class to your `<body>` tag (or a `<div class="YOURCLASS">...</div>` around your content), depending on how your template is configured.

[image]

Then simply create a new rule in your template's CSS file, using the class you specified.

E.g.
Add `mycustomclass` to the "Page class" field in your menu item, and put this in your CSS file:

```
.mycustomclass p {font-color:red;} // Make text red on this particular page
```

**Alt. 2 - Custom CSS modules**
Several modules are available for this purpose. One example is [Custom CSS](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/14053), a module that allows you to add any CSS code and publish it to the pages you want to style.

A similar option is [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/16359), a module that lets you add HTML, JavaScript **and CSS** to your pages. The code can be added to the `<head>` tag automatically.

**Alt 3. - load additional CSS stylesheet**
Another alternative is to check the current menu item ID in your template's `index.php` file, and load another CSS stylesheet if needed:

```
<?php 
   $currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
   if ($currentMenuId == "14") {
       echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">';
   }
?>
```

Comment: I use the first alternative (with page class) but are you aware of a way to apply these styles in the editor? For example titles don't have the same font depending on the category they belong to, how can I apply the font inside the editor depending on the page they are displayed on?

Answer (score 10):

One of my favorite approaches is to create dynamic classes for the body element.

So:

```
<?php
  $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
  $menu   = $app->getMenu();
  $active = $menu->getActive();
  $class  = $active->alias . " pageid-" . $active->id;
?>
<body class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
```

Some examples of what the above code will produce is:

Home page:

```
<body class="home pageid-13">
```

About us page:

```
<body class="about-us pageid-15">
```

Now you can create custom specific styles per page, using the above classes.

---

### Update 2023

#### Getting the menu in Joomla 4:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$activeMenuitem = $menu->getActive();
```

https://docs.joomla.org/Menu_and_Menuitems_API_Guide

Comment: I like this solution, it's very useful, and easy to implement. +1

Comment: Just started Joomla and like @johanpw, I like this solution.

Comment: @lance2k Hello. If you are on Joomla4 read this guide, in order to use up-to-date code: https://docs.joomla.org/Menu_and_Menuitems_API_Guide

Answer (score 4):

This is another method of doing the same thing.

Goes above the doctype:

```
<?php
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive();
  $pageclass = '';

  if (is_object($menu))
    $pageclass = $menu->params->get('pageclass_sfx');
?>
```

Goes in your index where your body class is:

```
<body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? htmlspecialchars($pageclass) : 'default'; ?>">
```

Now, anything you add into the menu item's page class will appear in the body id. Any menu item without a class will automatically be body id="default".

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the content area, use **"Page Class"** in **"Page Display"** Tab inside your menu item.

If you want to change the style for the entire menu item page, try this:

- By item id:

As an example in the default *Protostar* template you can see in the `<body>` tag a class like:

```
<body class="... itemid-101 ...">
```

This corresponds to the menu item with the Id 101. From here you can add a class in the file [user.css](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_a_custom_CSS_with_Protostar) for the new CSS class `.item101 {}`, this works for the entire `<body>` tag.

The code used here, in the index.php file:

`<?php echo $itemid ? ' itemid-' . $itemid : ''; ?>`

- By active menu item, find here more examples:
  https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_Page_Class_Suffix_in_Template_Code
- Via extension:
  http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/style-a-design/templating/css2switch-basic

Regards.