# Min and max height on image

Tags: styling

I am very new to Joomla. I normally just do all my styles with CSS, but Joomla is a little more frustrating.

How do I set a min and max height on an image? Also is there a way to adjust the margin and padding?

[Here](http://aglcounseling.com/) is the site. I am working with the company logo in the header. It is dynamic and changes size as the window changes size. When the window is 768px wide, the text is so small, it is unreadable. shrink the window to 767px, the logo gets way too big.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/tutorials/adding-a-custom-style-sheet, then just add your desired CSS

Comment: Thank you so much. This is even better then I was hoping. If you add this as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Comment: These 2 Q/A are good resources as well: **http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template/** & **http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5398/adding-custom-css-styling-on-some-of-my-pages**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will firstly need to create a `custom.scss` file is it doesn't exist. For more information on this, have a look at the Gantry 5 documentation:

http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/tutorials/adding-a-custom-style-sheet

Once you have you custom SCSS file, apply your changes and it will automatically be recompiled.