# How do I modify the CSS class on a specific page in a Joomla 3 template?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, css, gantry

I upgrade a site template from Nebulae - version 1.6.3 to the latest version 1.16. [Nebulae Template](https://rockettheme.com/docs/joomla/templates/nebulae/)

The new template change the rt-container children class from this:

[image]
[image]

to this:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the layout reversed because the class changed inside rt-container. I manually changed the grid class on `templates/rt_nebulae/html/layouts/body_mainbody.php` but it applied to all pages:

http://test.local/services/programming-services

http://test.local/services/design-services

http://test.local/services/others

templates/rt_nebulae/html/layouts/body_mainbody.php

```
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die();

gantry_import('core.gantrylayout');

/**
 *
 * @package gantry
 * @subpackage html.layouts
 */
class GantryLayoutBody_MainBody extends GantryLayout {
    var $render_params = array(
        'schema'        =>  null,
        'pushPull'      =>  null,
        'classKey'      =>  null,
        'sidebars'      =>  '',
        'contentTop'    =>  null,
        'contentBottom' =>  null
    );
    function render($params = array()){
        global $gantry;

        $fparams = $this-> _getParams($params);

        // logic to determine if the component should be displayed
        $display_mainbody = !($gantry->get("mainbody-enabled",true)==false && JRequest::getVar('view') == 'featured');
        $display_component = !($gantry->get("component-enabled",true)==false && (JRequest::getVar('option') == 'com_content' && JRequest::getVar('view') == 'featured'));
        ob_start();

        $mbClasses = trim("rt-grid-" . trim($fparams->schema['mb'] . " " . $fparams->pushPull[0]));
        $mbClasses = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $mbClasses);
// XHTML LAYOUT
?>          
<?php if ($display_mainbody) : ?>
<div id="rt-main" class="<?php echo $fparams->classKey; ?>">
    <div class="rt-container">
        <div class="<?php echo $mbClasses; ?>">
            <?php if (isset($fparams->contentTop)) : ?>
            <?php if (controlsDisplay('content-top')): ?><div class="scroller-enabled"><?php endif; ?>
            <div id="rt-content-top">
                <?php echo $fparams->contentTop; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <?php if (controlsDisplay('content-top')): ?></div><?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($display_component) : ?>
                <?php if ($gantry->get('articlestyle')!='') : ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $gantry->get('articlestyle'); ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="rt-block">
                        <div id="rt-mainbody">
                            <div class="component-content">
                                <jdoc:include type="component" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                <?php if ($gantry->get('articlestyle')!='') : ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (isset($fparams->contentBottom)) : ?>
            <?php if (controlsDisplay('content-bottom')): ?><div class="scroller-enabled"><?php endif; ?>
            <div id="rt-content-bottom">
                <?php echo $fparams->contentBottom; ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <?php if (controlsDisplay('content-bottom')): ?></div><?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $fparams->sidebars; ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

I want only to modify the CSS grid class on `http://test.local/services/programming-services` page. How should we do this in Joomla 3.10.12? I'm a complete newbie to Joomla and couldn't find much info on Nebulae's docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rocket Theme Nebulae theme is based on the Gantry 4 framework. That means that you will be able to find the information you are looking for in the Gantry 4 documentation. I has been a while since I worked with this template, but as far as I can remember you can create an override of the layout and configure the positioning.

If that is not possible, take a look at this page [in the Gantry 4 documentation](https://docs.gantry.org/gantry4/advanced/creating-a-new-layout). It describes how you can override the file `body_mainbody.php` and add your own classes to the HTML.

NB: Joomla! 3 has reached end-of-life status on 17 August 2023, so you might want to think about upgrading to at least Joomla! 4 to keep your website stable and safe.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to specifically modify the page css with the help of this `https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5400/17539`